# Do <cctype> functions work with Unicode?

Tags: c++

Page 601 of the C++ Special Edition says...

`In <ctype.h> and <cctype>, the standard library provides a set of useful functions for dealing with ASCII and similar character sets.`

Would Unicode fall under this "similar character sets" category?

Comment: As long as you only use the subset of unicode code points in the range 0->127 and use the UTF-8 encoding then functions in the above headers should work fine.

Comment: There's a nice Open Source library from IBM who's name I can't remember right offhand that has a giant database and a bunch of functions that let you ask interesting questions about Unicode characters.  I'd recommend that over any of the standard library stuff.  `wchar_t` is so vague as to be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode support has been a major pain point of the language. You will have to set a locale for non-ANSI and use the `wchar_t` variants. The exact meaning of the `wchar_t` varies with implementation. E.g:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_ca.UTF-8");
```

Take a look at the the Unicode Consortium page on [locales](http://cldr.unicode.org/index).

Comment: Hmm...then would <cwctype> be guaranteed to work, or will it vary with implementation?

Comment: It'd work. What I meant is `wchat_t` does not specify a format like UCS-4. All it says is that they represent multibyte data. The default format varies across systems.

Answer (score 0):

Features from `<cctype>` are not really usable to support Unicode encodings.

I think that the note on *similar character sets* is strictly related to family of 8-bit character encodings, for example [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code).

However, notice that it is correct to consider ASCII a subset (or variant) of Unicode. If you use UTF-8 encoding of Unicode, then the first 128 code points are the same as 128 ASCII characters and the first 256 characters are identical to Latin-1. Meaning, all ASCII is considered as valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the implementation. C++ certainly allows it, but doesn't mandate it. You'd need a `CHAR_BIT` >= 20. In practice, no implementation does so. Unicode is usually supported by `wchar_t` and the corresponding `<cwctype>` header.